# Where can you find tools needed to further upgrade your weapon?

Tags: the-last-of-us

I have over 100 parts ready to be used to upgrade my weapons, but all the upgrades now need at least 1 tool (ones that look like pliers). Where can I find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In **Chapter 4: Bill's Town - Graveyard**. After meeting up with Bill and receiving a nail bomb, look for a toolbox with the tool upgrade and some parts on the left side of the room.
2. In **Chapter 5: Pittsburgh - Alone and Forsaken**, after opening the garage door and entering the room with some "pretty gnarly stuff" inside, it's to your immediate left.
3. In **Chapter 6: Suburbs - Sewers**, after Ellie gets the generator started so you can cross the water, move forward but keep an eye out for a door on your left leading to a storage room. If you miss this one, you can also find it in the remains of a survivors living area, up the stairs, into the door on the right, and between a set of bunk beds.
4. **Chapter 8: The University - Science Building** has a tool upgrade on the floor you enter in Room 104 (a lecture room). You'll need a shiv to unlock the door.
5. **Chapter 10: Bus Depot - Highway Exit** holds the final upgrade. After encountering everybody's favourite ungulate/ruminant and entering the back of the depot, look out for the FEDRA tents (before passing through the bus that leads to the next area). One of them holds the last upgrade.